# Css positioning divs when they are inside another

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, position

I'm trying to position lock icon inside div. It is in the same div as input and when the input is focused my icon doesn't move to down like the input field. When I do it as icon inside div I am using parent with position absolute and child with position abosolute. But when I try to do it with div containing div with icon what should be a parent?
Example code:

```css
.backgr {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
}

.fa-lock {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
}

.shit {
  position: relative;
  /* border:solid 1px; */
  /* border:solid 1px; */
}

.wrapper {
  /* border-color: red;
        border:1px solid; */
  position: relative;
  /* border:solid 1px; */
}

.backgr {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
}

.fa-lock {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
}

.shit {
  position: relative;
  /* border:solid 1px; */
  /* border:solid 1px; */
}

.wrapper {
  /* border-color: red;
        border:1px solid; */
  position: relative;
  /* border:solid 1px; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="backgr">
    <i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="shit">
    <input id="password" class="login_input" type="password" placeholder="hasło" name="password" id="password" />
    <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
input {
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
.backgr {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 5px;
    z-index:9;
}
.shit {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
i.fa.fa-eye-slash {
    position: absolute;
    /* right: 0; */
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class = wrapper>
                <div class=backgr>
            <i class ="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i>
                </div>
            <div class="shit">
            <input id = "password" class="login_input" type="password" placeholder="hasło" name = "password" id = "password">
            <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>
        </div>
```

By ypur question what i understand
I have showed it some thing like this